# No class found exception while using json-lib in android

Tags: java, android, json-lib

I am taking the input from the web, which is an ***Xml file*** and converting into a ***Json data*** using the library **json-lib** . I have created a user library and added the following jars into it:-

1. json-lib-2.3-jdk15.jar
2. commons-collections.jar
3. commons-lang.jar
4. commons-logging.jar
5. commons-beanutils.jar
6. ezmorph-1.0.6.jar
7. xom-1.1.jar

But still gives the following error:-

**08-04 13:58:31.642: ERROR/dalvikvm(484): Could not find class 'net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer$CustomElement', referenced from method net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer.addNameSpaceToElement**

Can anyone help me out in resolving this issue.

Comment: `'net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer$CustomElement'` why is there a $?

Comment: @Sherif i believe that is because its a nested class within XMLSerializer.. so net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer.CustomElement is it's real path.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have a sdk level / jdk level conflict. I mean dalvik can't get the byte code of the CustomElement class of your librairy as it is compiled with to recent features for your SDK like annotations for instance.

Or there is a conflicting librairy json-lib in some other of your jars or lib folders.

(the 3 first comments are not relevant, it's just the way inner classes are compiled, using a $)

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: Ya i think so i had conflict jars,but it still gives the following error:-                                                        08-04 15:05:14.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(366): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 15:05:14.303: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(366): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
How to resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure you librairies are compatible with Dalvik ?

Answer (score 0):

Since android already support json [org.json](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) a different json library may conflict. (You can download the jar [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20090211))

Try to use this library instead of an external library on android.

BTW: You can also use this library if you need on any java code (not only android)